# Can I use sbt to build my own stand-alone console?

Tags: scala, sbt, lifty

I really like sbt and its extendibility. I'd like to use it as the basis of my own little stand-alone console-like tool. Basically it would have a bunch of tasks and such. I'm thinking something like [Lifty](http://lifty.github.com/), but I'd like to have one command that would launch sbt, load any relevant plugins (whether Lifty or my own), and then present users with my own custom prompt with a limited set of tasks & settings available.

Is this possible without jumping through a lot of hoops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is, and stuff like Play and Akka do exactly that. You might get an inkling on how to do all you need with [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras), or looking at the above-mentioned projects.